# AutoCompleteTextView click event on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete, onclick

I have successfully implemented my AutoCompleteTextView which is based off an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) query and is placed in an array adapter. That's all working beautifully, however I can't get my onclickevent working.

I just want to create an intent to pass the selected value to a new activity. I know how to create an onclicklistener. I am just unsure about how to apply it to the dropdown box of the AutoCompleteTextView.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nevermind. I've solved it. I was just executing poorly. The code below autocompletes my textview based off a simple SELECT SQLite statement and executes when the user selects the university from the dropdown list.

The onclick event creates a new intent and starts a new activity passing the selection to this activity within the intent.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_university);
String[] universities = myDbHelper.getAllUnis(db);

// Print out the values to the log
for(int i = 0; i < universities.length; i++)
{
    Log.i(this.toString(), universities[i]);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, universities);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);

//textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Campus.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("university_name", arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
        bundle.putLong("_id", arg3);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

putExtra function can be used for this purpose.

Here is an example...

Form the sending activity:

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
            ApplicationInfo x = appinstalled.get(pos);
            PackageInfo y = appinstall.get(pos);
            //Intent i = new Intent(InstalledPackages.this, Information.class);
            i = new Intent(InstalledPackages.this, Information.class);
            i.putExtra("i",x);
            i.putExtra("j", y);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

On the receiving side:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    ApplicationInfo i = (ApplicationInfo)myIntent.getParcelableExtra("i");
    PackageInfo j = (PackageInfo)myIntent.getParcelableExtra("j");
```

Comment: I've created a clickevent that works for my listview activities in my app & i've adapted it for the AutoCompleteTextView, however when I click on on item I want from the dropdown list the event is not firing so I'm obviously not referencing to the dropdown list properly so i am really just asking for a generic bit of code illustrating how to fire an even from the clicking of the drop down list!! cheers